# Will JavaScript hyperlink field update require any updates to external site?

Tags: javascript, integration, wordpress

One of my web design clients uses Salesforce extensively, and we have it integrated to their WordPress site. I'm not terribly familiar with Salesforce myself and I want to double check if there is anything that needs to be done on the external site to comply with this update. I know that's a big question that requires specifics - just a general suggestion of where to start would be very helpful.

I've searched this forum and read the Salesforce update emails and knowledge articles about the update.

Answer (score 3):

The external site won't care, but JavaScript buttons won't work in Lightning. You will need to create an Action in order to open the external site, or change to a normal URL button, if possible.